# Linux: I need to tunnel out through a second machine and then to a proxy server

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding

I have 2 servers running CentOS 6

I have a server A, that has 2 network cards. eth0 is a private test network. eth1 is the corporate network, where a proxy server must be used to access the internet. On this server I use

```
      export http_proxy=http://proxyserver:3128/
```

and am able to access the internet.

I have a server B that has 1 network card. eth0 is on the same private test network as above.

I want Server B to be able to connect to the internet. Obviously my only option is to somehow go through server A. I unsuccessfully tried to setup a squid proxy as well as SSH tunneling, I do not know enough about either, nor do I know enough to be able to google search for a decent example/help. My linux skills are seriously lacking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to create a `ssh` tunnel from B to A.

```
server_B$ ssh -Nf -L 1234:proxyserver:3128 server_A
```

`-N` tells `ssh` not to start a shell on server_A and `-f` that it should go to background right after prompting for that password.

The interesting part is the `-L`, which specifies the port-forwarding -- I am still amazed what can be done with that:

`1234` is the local (i.e. on server_B) port `ssh` will listen to. (That can of course be 3128 as well, but I have chosen a different value to illustrate the difference.)

`proxyserver` must be reachable from server_A; `3128` finally is the port to which you will be redirected.

As the port-forwarding is transparent, you should be able to use your proxy on server_B (once the tunnel is open) with

```
export http_proxy=http://localhost:1234/
```